# sched_setscheduler always returns EPERM before login

Tags: c, linux, posix

sched_setscheduler always return EPERM(errno 1) before login.
but After login, sched_setscheduler returns OK.

The process of calling sched_setscheduler has the following information.

- uid : 0
- gid : 0
- euid : 0
- all of capability is on

But I don't find out the relation between sched_setscheduler and login.

login means that id/password have been entered to console's login.

## login:

## password:

The following is how to call sched_setscheduler call

void *pthread_entry(void* args) {

```
struct sched_param param = {0};
param.sched_priority = 30;
int ret = sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_RR, &param);
```

}

Before login, sched_setcheduler always return EPERM(errno).
After login, sched_setcheduler return ok value

sched_setcheduler want to have cap_sys_nice capablity and I've confirmed that cap_sys_nice is on from process.

but I guess that login make cap_sys_nice to be allowed

Comment: What does login mean in this context and how do you call sched_setscheduler?  Please provide some clarification and code.

Comment: I'vd added your comment in top

Comment: Thanks. How is your program invoked before and after login?